# Why doesn't tensorflow's 'list_local_devices' and 'list_physical_devices' detect my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using an Anaconda environment with tensorflow-gpu. I have a GTX 1050TI with the latest drivers. I have also installed CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN (version compatible with CUDA 10.1). However tensorflow doesn't detect my GPU for some reason.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Output:
Num GPUs Available:  0

Code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Output:

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 15520470840604058286
]
2021-05-14 22:04:35.496144: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Could you post the tensorflow version as well, as also check if CUDA query returns a GPU device or not

Comment: i am using Tensorflow 2.3.0.

Comment: Another question, is your `nvidia-smi` command working and it's output along with the output of the `nvcc -V` command. It would also be helpful if you could provide the OS/distro you are running as well.

Comment: Make sure all the required software installed as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements). Do check all the environment variables are set properly as per [linux doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#linux_setup) and [windows doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup). Thanks!